# Can I remove or alter a PostgreSQL table's geometry dimension constraint via a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, constraints, postgis

### The question

I am using Rails 2.3 with the [Spatial Adapter plugin](https://github.com/fragility/spatial_adapter) and a Postgres 8.4 database with PostGIS extension.

A while ago, a geometry field has been added to a table via a migration like this:

```
add_column :my_table, :the_geom, :geometry, :srid => 4326
```

Along with the field, a table dimension constraint is created. In this case it makes sure the geometry entered into the `the_geom` field *does have exactly two dimensions*.

Now, I'd like to add geometries with more than 2 dimensions. **What Rails migration code could I use to either change the constraint to allow more than two dimensions or remove it altogether?**

### What didn't work

When I create a new geometry field via the `add_column` method, I know I can use the `:with_z` and `:with_m` options to increase the number of dimensions allowed (the constraint would allow up to four dimension when using both options).
However, when using these options with the `change_column` command, it doesn't seem to have any effect on the constraint.
I don't want to remove the column and re-add it, because then I lose all data.

I know, I can use raw SQL to remove the constraint (I could also use a migration or rake task as a wrapper). The problem with this is, that it doesn't have an effect on the test database, because it is always created from scratch when I run all tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to alter a geometry column without turning to raw SQL via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`.

Unfortunately raw SQL statements do not make it into the Rails database schema and so the constraints remain in the DB when it is recreated (for tests for example).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the spatial adapter fields/options so this code might be a little off, but how about something like this?

```
class UpgradeGeometryMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :my_table, :the_geom, :the_geom_old
    add_column    :my_table, :the_geom, :geometry, :srid => 4326, :with_z => true, :with_m => true

    # Add some code here to iterate through all of your records in the 
    # :the_geom_old table and copy them into the new :the_geom field

    remove_column :my_table, :the_geom_old

    # Add any indices required for :the_geom
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to be a valid option, but it turns out it doesn't work. I found out that the dimension constraint checks for an exact number of dimensions (`ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2);`). Note the equal sign `=`. I thought it would allow _less_ dimensions than the maximum, too (`<=2`). The problem with this is, that when copying all the geometries from `the_geom_old` to `the_geom` the new constraint - which _demands_ 4 dimensions - prevents me from doing so, because some of them only have 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

*Some* raw SQL statements end up in the database schema. The following modifies the column type from geometry to geography:

```
class ChangePostGisGeometryToGeography < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geography(MULTIPOLYGON,4326);
    SQL
  end
end
```

The migration modifies `db/schema.rb` correctly :

```
-    t.spatial  "geom", :limit => {:srid=>4326, :type=>"multi_polygon"}
+    t.spatial  "geom", :limit => {:srid=>4326, :type=>"multi_polygon", :geographic=>true}
```

*(Tested under Rails 3.2.13 and activerecord-postgis-adapter 0.6.6)*